# How can I make a script run at a standard time interval

Tags: scripts

My end goal is to get a notification when my isp dynamic ip address changes. I'm using curl -o icanhazip.com (file) to write the ip address to a text file, and I'd like to write a script to make the get request and compare it with a file, update it and send me a notification if there'd been a change. The script has to be run automatically at a given time interval, like once a day. How do I get the script to run like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `cron` and specifically for a cronjob

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto